# WPF button takes two clicks to fire Click event

Tags: wpf, calendar, focus, controls

I have a TabItem which contains a calendar control and a button. The issue is that when the calendar's selected date is the same as the previously selected date, the button takes two clicks to fire its Click event.

I have implemented the selectedDatesChanged event of the calendar to solve this problem when the current selected date is different from the previous selection. The code is as below:

```
selectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.CaptureMouse();
    this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to have the same effect shown in the above function when the selectedDate of the calendar does not differ from the previously selected date.
I tried handling the GotFocus and MouseUp events, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could solve this issue?

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: I solved the problem by handling the PreviewMouseUp event of the calendar.

Comment: if your problem is resolved, would recommend you to publish your solution as answer and then accept it. Users with similar problem would see an accepted answer rather than a comment as a solution.

Comment: This is still an issue with the calendar control. At any time you give focus to it, you need to click other controls twice to get a response. Anyone got a good solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was the best answer I found on the web. It's still not perfect because it doesn't help with buttons that are marked as IsDefault or IsCancel

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);
  if (Mouse.Captured is Calendar || Mouse.Captured is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem)
  {
    Mouse.Capture(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: The original source seems to be here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b4413872-59d0-4a06-9d20-8d21de126dc6/calendar-not-losing-focus-wpf-40?forum=wpf

Answer (score 6):

You could simply write:

```
Mouse.Capture(null);
```

This will solve the issue of mouse holding focus